# Refering to an externally defined API for a Function event in SAM

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

In my SAM templates, my team has defined an [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html) that is mostly to our liking. I would like to debug this API locally, but it isn't set explicitly as an `Event` under our `Function`. So `sam local start-api` fails with the error

```
Error: Template does not have any APIs connected to Lambda functions
```

How can I convince SAM that the API we have defined is the event meant to invoke this Lambda? What should I do to test this locally?

edit - to clarify, the current template structure looks something like

```
  Lambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
...
  LambdaRole:
....
  MAILAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this implements all the gateway params we defined so I wont mark this as resolved yet, but this is a promising start!

This allowed me to start the API as expected locally

```
 Events:
    Api:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: /
        Method: post
        RestApiId: 
          Ref: MAILAPI
```

With (of course) our API resource defined under the MAILAPI label (edited question to show this)